# Select region in firefox for printing to pdf?

Tags: firefox, pdf, printing

Can we select region in a webpage and printing the region to a pdf file?

For example, in https://www2.cisl.ucar.edu/docs/hpss/kerberos, I want to print the part under "Kerberos basics", not the parts in the left column (i.e. "Resources", "Getting Started", "Help Desk"), nor the parts at the top of "Kerberos basics".

Thanks!

Comment: I do not know if Firefox supports such a feature. But in Chromium you can simply select the part you want to print ant select `print ...` in the context-menu (works also for the page you mentioned above).

Comment: I assume by "printing to PDF", you're referring to using a PDF printer driver, so the issue is just how to print a selection.  If the print option for Selection is greyed out, there are a number of add-ons that will let you preview and remove anything you don't want printed.  I use one called [Print Edit](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/print-edit/).  Another one I use is [PrintFriendly](http://www.printfriendly.com/browser_tool).